# AppleArchive Framework isn't working fine

Tags: ios, swift, archive

I have been working on **AppleArchive** [Official Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applearchive) with *Real Device*. But I get **compile time error**:

1. Cannot find **FilePath**.
2. Cannot find **ArchiveByteStream**.
3. Cannot find **FilePermissions**.

And code sample from **Apple** is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_single_files).

Xcode version: **12.4**

Device Version: **14.4.2**

I have worked on it before some months so that time I was able to **import AppleArchive Framework**. But now there is not suggestion for importing it. Now I think this Framework has been removed from Apple.
Look at image:
[image: here]